# How to activate STK on Quectel EC20 GSM Modem

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim-toolkit

command, Am using Quectel EC20 GSM Modem (4G), i try to access SIM ToolKit to recharge on M1 SIM (Singapore).i know i need to activate STK.

```
 i tried `at+stgi=0` but it return `ERROR`
```

any idea how to start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate the sim toolkit on Quectel EC20 GSM Modem (4G) you have to use below code which is not in the manual.

```
AT+QSTK=1,0,300
```

> AT+QSTK=mode,alphabet,timeout

**Mode**
0 Disable STK functionality
1 Enable STK functionality

**Alphabet set.**
0 GSM character set
1 UCS2 character set

Timeout for response in second
1-300-65535